# Range not defined correctly

Tags: python, range

When I type `to_float_hours(0,1,0)` it returns a value but when I type `to_float_hours(0,0,1)` it doesn't.

Additionally, if I type `to_float_hours(0,61,0)` it returns a value and when I type `to_float_hours(0,1,59)` it doesn't.

Why is the range for minutes anything greater than 1 and seconds it's anything between 0 and 58?

I want the the function to only return a value when both the input for minutes and seconds are between and including 0 to 59.

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    acceptable_range = list(range(0,59))
    while minutes and seconds in acceptable_range:
        hours = hours
        minutes = minutes/60
        seconds = seconds/3600
        total = hours+minutes+seconds
        return total
```

Comment: doing while `minutes and seconds in acceptable_range:` is the same as `while minutes==True and seconds in acceptable_range:`

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks!

Comment: count is starting from 0 and ending at 58. 59 in this case is equal to next hour.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **stop** is exclusive in [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) function and means that values given by range function will be from **start** to **stop-1**

```
acceptable_range = list(range(0,60))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix the logic in the While (what @painor said) and fix the range by adding one (because we start in zero).

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    acceptable_range = list(range(0,60))
    while minutes in acceptable_range and seconds in acceptable_range:
        hours = hours
        minutes = minutes/60
        seconds = seconds/3600
        total = hours+minutes+seconds
        return total
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` function doesn't commit until the last value. Your current range should be **(0,60)** since after 59, the seconds or minutes automatically changes to the next preceding minute or second so the value gets updated to 0 rather than 60. So the correct range is **(0,60)** wherein the python actually won't consider the last number present in the range but a number before it.

So creating `list(range(0,60))` is actually creating `[0,1,2,...59]`

Another problem is you should be using `if` statement rather than a `while` loop since you want a condition to be executed only and only if the numbers are in acceptable range.

Also, I don't understand why you want to restrict minutes and seconds. They can even go beyond 60.

---

Anyway, here's the working version of your code :-

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    acceptable_range = list(range(0,60))
    if seconds in acceptable_range and minutes in acceptable_range:
        hours = hours
        minutes = minutes/60
        seconds = seconds/3600
        total = hours+minutes+seconds
        return total
```